# how to make page scroll smooth when link click

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can i make the page scroll smoothly back to the top with this link? I am able to achieve this with jQuery on other links i have but cannot get this one to work?

```
<a class="w-toplink active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>

.w-toplink {
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: -50px;
right: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top:15px;
line-height: 50px;
height: 30px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
background-color: #333;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #fff;
display: none;
opacity:0; transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;}


.w-toplink.active {
bottom: 30px;
opacity: 0.7;
}

.w-toplink:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Jquery code works fine on other links but i cannot get it to apply to the above link?

```
jQuery(function($){ $.localScroll({filter:'.w-toplink'}); });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwbjOd

Comment: Can you paste the JavaScript/jQuery you are using that isn't working correctly?

Comment: the jQuery code is working fine however i cannot get it to apply to this link for some reason. The line of code that would apply is: jQuery(function($){ $.localScroll({filter:'.w-toplink'}); });

Comment: Is it wrapped in `document.load`? Can you show us your full JS code?

Comment: here's a code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwbjOd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `scrollTop()` - it's been in jQuery since 1.2.3
http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop

```
$('.w-downlink').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
});
```

You don't need to use the `smoothScroll` function.

Here's a forked version of your pen: http://codepen.io/akwright/pen/rVWjjv

Comment: brilliant! no idea how long i've been trying to get that to work!

Comment: @iamdanmorris Glad to help! Sometimes another pair of eyes is all it takes :)  If that worked for you, would you mind marking it as the correct answer?